# Spring Social authentication filter not working, how can I debug it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm having trouble with Spring SocialAuthenticationFilter, I see that it's loaded in the filter chain but when I access "/auth/facebook?code=...", it does not process that input.

Here is my WebSecurityConfig's configure method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //@formatter:off
    http
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .apply(new SpringSocialConfigurer());
    //@formatter:on
}
```

And in the output I get this about filter chain:

```
2015-07-06 12:42:08.400  INFO 28531 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4cb4e09b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4ac65d33, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3181e122, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3492e7fd, 
org.springframework.social.security.SocialAuthenticationFilter@1b2b4922
,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@392294cd, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@794fa3a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3f3e8762, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@3d31d08d, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@31e84fe1, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@d8d9225]
```

And this about URL matching:

```
2015-07-06 12:43:22.075 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/css/**'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.075 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/js/**'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.075 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/images/**'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.075 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.075 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/info'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.075 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/health'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/error'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/oauth/token'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/oauth/token_key'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/oauth/check_token'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.076 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3f8843c2
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/auth/facebook'; against '/logout'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.077 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.078 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.078 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.078 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.078 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.078 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73; Attributes: [#oauth2.throwOnError(permitAll)]
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.078 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.079 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@361b4478, returned: 1
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.079 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.079 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.079 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /auth/facebook?code=AQB2OSMHtYeuu-***-5tQvCyxOGkZCQsnAxFgCKYRE248MXPqEb5VI63W6IJrNyw36losbP3qx73 reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.085 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /auth/facebook
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.086 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/auth/facebook]
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.088 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
    2015-07-06 12:43:22.089 DEBUG 28531 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Please, tell me if you see sth wrong, or you can suggest a debugging method.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other `Http` element in your application? Like other configuration classes implementing the `configure(HttpSecurity http)` method. If so, post it here.
FYI, the `permitAll()` that you use here doesn't make the path unsecure, it just tells that there is no authorization bound to it (like a specific role required to get in). What you're probably looking for is the `anonymous()` method which allows any user to access the url with an `AnonymousAuthentication`.